# SQL Server, what's wrong with my freetext search example?

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

I'm experimenting with freetext searching on SQL Server 2008. But I have problem to make it work. Can anyone spot what's wrong in my script:

- Is it setup incorrectly?
- Is my queries invalid?
- Any other clues?

Why does the queries at the end give no result?

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Set up fulltext search
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
IF FullTextServiceProperty('IsFullTextInstalled') <> 1
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Full Text Service is not installed, script is aborted.'
    RETURN
END

IF DatabaseProperty(DB_NAME(), 'IsFulltextEnabled') <> 1
    EXEC sp_fulltext_database 'enable'

IF NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT  1
    FROM    sys.fulltext_catalogs (NOLOCK)
    WHERE   name = 'searchcatalog_test'
)
BEGIN
    CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG searchcatalog_test
    WITH ACCENT_SENSITIVITY = OFF
END


----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Set up table
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
IF OBJECT_ID('freetext_test', 'U') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    EXEC SP_FULLTEXT_TABLE 'freetext_test', 'DROP'
    DROP TABLE freetext_test
END

CREATE TABLE dbo.freetext_test
(
    freetext_id INT IDENTITY
,   freetext_data   NVARCHAR(MAX)
    CONSTRAINT pk_freetext_test PRIMARY KEY (freetext_id)
)

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON freetext_test
(
    freetext_data   LANGUAGE 0  -- 0 = Neutral
)
KEY INDEX pk_freetext_test ON searchcatalog_test
WITH CHANGE_TRACKING AUTO

INSERT  INTO freetext_test(freetext_data)
        SELECT  N'Some text to test free text searching'
UNION   SELECT  N'Another text to test with'
UNION   SELECT  N'Another test string'
UNION   SELECT  N'Today is a sunny day'
UNION   SELECT  N'I wonder if anyone at StackOverflow can help me?'


----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Test section
----------------------------------------------------------------------------    
SELECT * FROM freetext_test

SELECT * FROM freetext_test WHERE FREETEXT (freetext_data, N'test')
SELECT * FROM freetext_test WHERE FREETEXT (freetext_data, N'string')
SELECT * FROM freetext_test WHERE FREETEXT (freetext_data, N'sunny')
SELECT * FROM freetext_test WHERE FREETEXT (freetext_data, N'StackOverflow')

SELECT * FROM freetext_test WHERE CONTAINS (freetext_data, N'text OR test')
SELECT * FROM freetext_test WHERE CONTAINS (freetext_data, N'string OR another')
SELECT * FROM freetext_test WHERE CONTAINS (freetext_data, N'today AND sunny')
SELECT * FROM freetext_test WHERE CONTAINS (freetext_data, N'anyone AND StackOverflow')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script works like a charm.

Could it be that you are executing the SELECTs too fast for the indexing engine to build the catalog?